# Не работает функция persistence()

Tags: python

Функция persistence():

```
def persistence(n):
    def multiply(number):
        ii = 1
        num = 2
        for i in range(0, n):
            ii *= str(int(number[i]))
            num += 1
            if ii == 1:
                break
        return num
    number = multiply(n)
    return number
```

Эта функция делает следующее:
Считывает кол-во необходимых умножений цифр n, пока не достигнет единицы.
Плохо обьясняю, лучше обьясню на примерах:

```
 persistence(39) => 3  # Because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
                       # and 4 has only one digit.

 persistence(999) => 4 # Because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
                       # 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2.

 persistence(4) => 0   # Because 4 is already a one-digit number.
```

Текст ошибки:

> ```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):   
>      File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 14, in persistence
>      number = multiply(n)   
>      File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 7, in multiply
>      str(number[i]) 
>      TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
> ```

Comment: Во-первых, в вашем коде нет строчки `str(number[i])` — вы запускаете не тот код, который нам показали. Во-вторых, к числу действительно нельзя обращаться как списку — код `number[i]` абсолютно бессмысленнен и действительно не должен работать.

Comment: Что по-вашему должно получаться в результате `39[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [55]: from operator import mul

In [56]: from functools import reduce

In [57]: def digits(value):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     while value:
    ...:         result += [value % 10]
    ...:         value //= 10
    ...:     return result

In [58]: def persistence(n, result=0):
    ...:     evaluate = reduce(mul, digits(n))
    ...:     if evaluate >= 10:
    ...:         return persistence(evaluate, result+1)
    ...:     return result + 1 if result else 0

In [59]: persistence(999)
Out[59]: 4
```